# How should Odyssey A 56 be scanned?: αἰεὶ δὲ μαλακοῖσι καὶ αἱμυλίοισι λόγοισιν

Tags: greek, metre, homer

[Odyssey A 56](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:tlg,0012,002:1:67&lang=original) goes thus:

> αἰεὶ δὲ μαλακοῖσι καὶ αἱμυλίοισι λόγοισιν

I find it difficult to scan this verse. The word μᾰλᾰκός has two short syllables, which must be preceded by a long one; and yet δὲ cannot possibly be long. Or can it?

In addition, the beginning of the verse, αἰεὶ, must be two long syllables, which must be followed by a long syllable, and yet it is δὲ that follows.

Answer (score 10):

There is a little-known rule of epic scansion in which, optionally, a word-initial sonorant (the nasals μ ν and the liquids ρ λ) may cause a preceding short vowel to scan long. Here's another example, *Odyssey* 18.399:

> μνηστῆρες δ᾽ ὁμάδησαν ἀνὰ μέγαρα σκιόεντα

-- where the second syllable of ἀνά scans long because of the following μ-.

The explanation for this seems to be that some such words once began with an additional s- (sm- etc.), which was later lost. But the phenomenon is not limited to words that historically had s- (and those that did do not consistently show it), so it seems to have been expanded into a license to lengthen certain syllables when metrically necessary.

Comment: Indeed, I had searched for s and wau in the etymology of μᾰλᾰκός but found none. I am glad to have learned of this (possibly analogical) rule! Do you happen to know of a good place online (or elsewhere) to find more information about specific rules of Homeric metre? We learned a couple of rules at university, like disappeared s/wau and disyllabic words like eu, but I don't remember whence those came.

Comment: @Cerberus, there are probably better references I'm not thinking of, but [here](http://www.aoidoi.org/articles/meter/intro.pdf) is a page you might find useful. If you want to dig deeper, M. L. West's *Greek Metre* is worth reading, though he devotes more space to dramatic meters than to Homer.

Comment: Thanks, I saw West mentioned somewhere else; I'll see whether I can find it somewhere. (As you suggested, the link told me nothing new.)